# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute when dir(module) indicates the function is present

Tags: python, import

I have a small python function:

```
def rebuildTilePDB(cost, cols, rows, kept):
    import scripts.domains.tiles as tt
    print dir(tt)
    d = tt.tileDictioanry(cost=cost, rows=rows, cols=cols)
    path = tiles.findTilePDB(d, kept)
    print path
```

Running it produces this:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'collections', 'filepaths', 'findTilePDB', 'os', 'tileDictionary', 'tilePDBDictionary']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./domains/pdb_builder.py", line 107, in <module>
    rebuildTilePDB("unit", rows=3, cols=4, kept=[1,2,3,4,5])
  File "./domains/pdb_builder.py", line 83, in rebuildTilePDB
    d = tt.tileDictioanry(cost=cost, rows=rows, cols=cols)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tileDictioanry'
```

I don't understand why I am getting the error, when the dir(tt) shows that the tt module has a function with the name tileDictionary.

Comment: `s/tileDictioanry/tileDictionary/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo : `tt.tileDictioanry` must be `tt.tileDictionary`.